# Content Profile fields in rules

Tags: 6, rules, users

I am using rules and want to access a field in a users content profile. how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules), there is a simple action that will allow you access to a user's content profile information.  In your rule, select "Add an action" and choose `Load Content Profile`:  [image: Load Content Profile]

On the next page, first choose which user to load (ex. logged in user, acting user, content author, etc). This depends on what Event you chose for the rule. Next choose which profile content type you want to load and click "Save".

Now, other actions you add after the first step (loading the content profile) will have access to the fields of the user's content profile. If you have the [Token module](http://drupal.org/project/token) installed, settings for new actions should have a fieldset titled `Token replacement patterns`. Expand that fieldset and you should see another fieldset titled `Replacement patterns for Content Profile`.  Expand that one to see all content profile tokens that can be used however you like.  Ex:[image: Token replacements]